# cargo install - specify toolchain? (Windows 10)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

I'm new to Rust, and installed it in a Conda environment via: `conda create -c conda-forge -n env_rust rust`

That all went fine, and after activating the Conda environment, rust and cargo are there:

```
rustc --version && cargo --version
rustc 1.53.0 (53cb7b09b 2021-06-17)
cargo 1.53.0 (4369396ce 2021-04-27)
```

I then setup JupyterLab and some other bits, no problem. When I tried installing the 'EvCxR kernel' for Jupyter via `cargo install evcxr_jupyter`, it failed with:

> error: linking with `link.exe` failed

I know that can be fixed by installing the MSVC toolchain from Visual Studio Build Tools (i.e. the 'C++ Desktop Development' workload). I already have a gcc toolchain environment from winlibs (https://winlibs.com/).

**How do I tell cargo to compile using the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` toolchain (and presumably the `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` linker) rather than `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`?**

Note that 'rustup' does not appear to have been installed within the conda environment as part of installing conda's 'rust' package, and I have never installed rust previously on the system (via rustup or any other means).

I tried `cargo install --target=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu evcxr_jupyter` but it errors with:

> error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`   |   = note: the
> `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` target may not be installed
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.

I read the explain advice, bit it is a little over my head for now....

**EDIT:** Further hunting about with `conda list -n env_rust` shows:

```
...
rust                      1.53.0               hf8d6059_0    conda-forge
rust-std-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
...
```

I'm guessing at least part of the problem, if this is solveable lies therein...
Doing a `conda search -c conda-forge/label/rust_dev rust*` reveals some other bits, but not the '...pc-windows-gnu' that I was hoping for and currently think might be what I would need...

```
rust-gnu_win-64               1.38.0               1  pkgs/main
rust-std-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc 1.48.0.dev20200918      h3e96b3b_1  conda-forge/label/rust_dev
rust_win-64          1.53.0.dev20210324      h582ca54_1  conda-forge/label/rust_dev
```

Going to have a sniff around `rust-gnu_win-64` and see what it might do for me....

**EDIT 2:** Which just seems to be an older version of Rust. I might just relent and install Rust via rustup-init.exe totally outside of miniconda and learn to use stuff via that...

**EDIT 3:** For anyone else that stumbles across it, those installer designations have nothing to do with the toolchain used after installation, it actually just reflects the toolchain that was used to build the installer....so the outcome is the same. See:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/1851
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2568

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a toolchain when building as follows:

```
cargo +toolchain build
```

So, in your case it will be:

```
cargo +x86_64-pc-windows-gnu build
```

Answer (score 0):

`rustup toolchain list` should give you list of all toolchains installed for rust compiling, something like below:

```
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

deafult one is used when when you compile rust code with `cargo <subcommand>`.

To change default toolchain `rustup default <toolchain-name>`. If you prefer to compile rust code only once with specific toolchain without changing default, you can do it with `cargo +<toolchain> <subcommand>` for e.g. `cargo +nightly run` (No need to write full toolchain name)

And if there is no toolchains before, you can install it with `rustup install <toolchain-name>`.